# Mobile Vision fails to detect numbers only

Tags: android, ocr, android-vision, text-recognition

Mobile Vision on Android works great on many texts with large enough font size. However, when a paper full of printed numbers scanned(like image below), it shows nothing.

I know it's a text recognizer, so tried to add few words around those large chunks of numbers, and boom, it worked.

Is there a way to enable it without word requirement?

**Update:** By accident I enlarged the photo below and rescan with Mobile Vision, and it worked. I guess when the font size increased the algorithm treated image as a road sign or plate, and therefore performed the desired action. Numbers recognized!

[image: example image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known issue of Google Vision API, both for mobile or in Cloud. They work well on longer lines of text, but fail on isolated charecters. They ignore it as a garbage. Only thing I can suggest you is to consider alternatives. Take a look at this SDK (free for may use cases): http://rtrsdk.com

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.